# S25FL064L flash isn´t answering

Tags: spi, flash-memories

I want to use the above flash memory to store some data with my MCU, but the flash isn´t answering on the `0x9F` instruction:

[image]

I use SPI mode 0 and a 125 kHz clock frequency. The `Reset` signal of the chip is high.

Is there anything that I must do first (i. e. to initialize the flash)?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your schematic?

Comment: Please take a look at my update

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question but have you scoped `Vcc` to confirm a stable 3v?

Comment: Yes, the power supply is stable. I have checked it a few seconds ago and there are no changes during the flash operation.